# Не передается данные сортировки в view Ajax

Tags: yii2

view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>

<?= $form->field($sort, 'sort')->dropDownList([
    1 => 'От дорогих к дешевым',
    2 => 'От дешёвых к дорогим',
    3 => 'По популярности',
    4 => 'Новинки',
    5 => 'По названию',
    6 => 'За рейтингом'
],
    [
        'prompt' => 'Выбрать',
        'onchange' => '
                        $.post(
                         "' . Url::toRoute('category/sort-item-category') . '",  // путь к действию контроллера
                         {
                         id : $(this).val(), // это id с выпадающего списка
                         cat_id : ' . Yii::$app->request->queryString . ', // тут id category                             }, // значение выбранного элемента списка
                         function(data){
                           $("div#model").html(data) // получение результата и подстановка в указанный div
                         }
                        )
                      ']) ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Тут же во View через foreach выводиться список товаров

```
<?php foreach ($model as $product) : ?>
    <div class="main_block">
        <?php if ($product['hit']) : ?>
            <div class="hit_product label label-success">Хит</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($product['new']) : ?>
            <div class="new_product label label-primary">Новинка</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($product['sale']) : ?>
            <div class="sale_product label label-danger">Распродажа</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="image_block">
            <?= Html::img('/web/uploads/products/' . Product::getImageName($product['img_id']), ['width' => '105', 'height' => '150']) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="title_block"><h1><?= $product['title'] ?></h1></div>
        <div class="category_block"><?= Category::getTitleCategory($product['category_id']) ?></div>
        <div class="rating_block">*****</div>
        <div class="price_block"><?= $product['price'] ?> грн.</div>
        <div class="btn_buy_block"><a href="<?= Url::to(['product/index', 'id' => $product['id']]) ?>">Купить</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

controller:

```
public function actionSortItemCategory()
{
    $id = (int)Yii::$app->request->post('id');// это я получаю из выподающего списка
    $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];// тут я получаю id category - http://site.loc/category/index?id=2

    if ($id == 1) { // делаю проверку если id == 1 то price => SORT_ASC
        $model = Product::find()
            ->where(['category_id' => $cat_id])
            ->andWhere(['status' => Product::STATUS_PRODUCT_ON])
            ->andWhere('price')
            ->asArray()
            ->orderBy(['price' => SORT_ASC]);

        return $model;
    } elseif ($id == 2) {// делаю проверку если id == 2 то price => SORT_DESC
        $model = Product::find()
            ->where(['category_id' => $cat_id])
            ->andWhere(['status' => Product::STATUS_PRODUCT_ON])
            ->andWhere('price')
            ->asArray()
            ->orderBy(['price' => SORT_DESC]);

        return $model;
    }
}
```

Я не могу понять как мне правильно передать во view то что отсортировалось, также у меня опять вылазит ошибка Response content must be a string or an object implementing __toString().